# Contextual keyboard shortcuts in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm coming from Sublime Text 3, where I used the [FileBrowser](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FileBrowser) package for file management. It had a nifty feature that allowed you to instantly open the current directory in explorer by pressing <kbd>\</kbd> with the sidebar selected. If the sidebar wasn't active (for example when editing text), nothing happened.

I'm trying to emulate this functionality in VS Code, which brings me to my question: Is it possible to have keyboard shortcuts that only work when a particular interface element (in my case the sidebar) is selected? The shortcut shouldn't do anything when editing text (I should be able to type a backslash), however, it should execute the command I want it to if the sidebar is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command for this: `revealFileInOS` (default)<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

`keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "\\",
    "command": "revealFileInOS",
    "when": "explorerViewletFocus && explorerViewletVisible"
},
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I cannot find any command `revealFileInOS`. I instead used `workbench.action.files.revealActiveFileInWindows` and it works just fine.

Comment: Installed it literally two days ago so I don't think so. Currently running version 1.13.0. This is odd however, as I can see in the [changelog](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_workbench) when they added the command. Can't think of a reason why it doesn't work.